# disabling all inputs in a particular form

Tags: jquery, variables, input, css-selectors

I can get the form id with

```
form_id= $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
```

I can disable/enable ALL the inputs with

```
if ($('.basket :input').is(':disabled') == true) {
$('.basket :input').removeAttr('disabled');
$(".basket :input").removeClass('disabled');
 $(':radio:not(:checked)').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hidden').next('label').removeClass('hidden');

});

} else {
$(".basket :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$(".basket :input").addClass('disabled');
$(':radio:not(:checked)').each(function(){
$(this).addClass('hidden').next('label').addClass('hidden');
});
```

what I am trying to do is disable only the input elements under form_id. I think it is maybe beacause I do not know how to subsitute variables in Jquery?

Comment: Just a comment for those reading this now, in the latest version of jQuery you should use `.prop("disabled", true);` rather than `.attr("disabled", "disabled")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the formID selector to the beginnning of your selectors e.g.

```
$('#' + form_id + ' .basket :input')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$("#"+form_id + " > :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

I wouldn't usually advocate using pseudo-selectors due to performance, so you could replace that with a discrete tagName list, should you wish.

Answer (score 0):

To disable all "inputs" inside the container with id "form_id":

```
$('#form_id').find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To enable all "inputs" inside the container with id "form_id":

```
$('#form_id').find(':input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Notice that the input psuedoselector does not necessarily mean only  tags. See [this page](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correctly:try this
To disable all input field inside form_id:

```
$('#form_id  input').attr('disabled' , 'disabled');
```

To enable all element:

```
$('#form_id input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

And if you want to learn How to get element from jquery and how jquery work: please read this article:
http://learningtechstuff.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/jquery-learning-series-for-beginners